# How to write a counter to a file in order?

Tags: python

I need to write a counter to a file in order of most occurring to least occurring but I am having a little trouble. When I print the counter it prints in order but when I call `counter.items()` and then write it to a file it writes them out of order.

I am trying to make it like this:

```
word      5
word2     4
word3     4
word4     3
```

Comment: How does your current code look? :)

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest you to use `collections.Counter` and then `Counter.most_common` will do what you're looking for:

Demo:

```
>>> c = Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba')
>>> c.most_common()
[('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('d', 2), ('e', 1)]
```

Write this to a file:

```
c = Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba')
with open("abc", 'w') as f:
    for k,v in  c.most_common():
        f.write( "{} {}\n".format(k,v) )
```

help on `Counter.most_common`:

```
>>> Counter.most_common?
Docstring:
List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

>>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
[('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]
```

Comment: Perhaps mention the [ordereddict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) as well...

Comment: Every time I turn around, I spot something handy in `collections` - that and `itertools` don't get nearly enough love IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
print sorted( my_counter.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

should work fine :)

dictionaries have no order which is what a counter is so you must sort the item list if you want it in some order... in this case ordered by the "value" rather than the "key"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  This prints it out in the desired order which is great, do you know a way to write it to a file though?  if I just say print my_counter it prints it out in order but not separated on each line and the real problem is with the writing to a file.  Thanks!